# C++ trouble passing pointer array to functions pointer array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

The 3 functions below are accessible by an array pointer ODE[3]:

```
double voltage(double v) {
    return Iapp - (gL*(v - EL)) - (gNa * pow(m, 3) * h * (v - ENa)) - (gK * pow(n, 4) * (v - EK));
}

double hdot(double h) {
    ah = 0.07*exp(-(v + 58) / 20);
    bh = 1 / (exp(-0.1*(v + 28)) + 1);
    return (phi * (ah*(1 - h) - bh*h));
}
double ndot(double n) {
    an = -0.01*(v + 34) / (exp(-0.1*(v + 34)) - 1);
    bn = 0.125 * exp(-(v + 44) / 80);
    return (phi * (an*(1 - n) - bn*n));
}

typedef double(*eqpointer)(void);
eqpointer ODE[3];
```

such that

```
ODE[0] = voltage;
ODE[1] = hdot;
ODE[2] = ndot;
```

In another function, ***midvalues***, ***oneloop*** and ***k1*** are pointers to arrays.

```
for (int j{ 0 }; j <= eq_num; ++j) k1[j] = dt*(ODE[j]());

for (int j{ 0 }; j <= eq_num; j++) midvalues[j] = oneloop[j] + k1[j] / 2;
```

I want to implement a loop:

```
for (int j{ 0 }; j <= eq_num; j++) ODE[j](midvalues[j]);
```

such that every function ODE[j] takes a corresponding pointer midvalues[j] as argument.

I'm guessing i need two pointers for the functions, 
one that takes no argument and returns the value, ie:  `ODE[j]()` 
and another that takes pointer position as argument and returns the value.

I have been struggling to find how to do this with no luck, would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think you might prefer a class, and make these voltage,hdot, etc 'methods' within the class.  I think....I'm having trouble understanding your question

Comment: Anyway, you can only have one type of pointer to a function, and it has to match the signature. In your case they all take a `double` parameter and return a `double`, so `double (*)(double)`.

Comment: `midvalue[j]` is an array pointer.         
using the loop `for (int j{ 0 }; j <= eq_num; j++) ODE[j](midvalues[j]);` i want to feed each `ODE[j]` with its corresponding `midvalues[j]`, while also being able to call ODE[j] without passing argument, using `ODE[j]()`

Comment: I think a single function that takes a pointer to a value instead of value could help. Could the function check for nullptr and dereference to use the value only when it is not nullptr?

Comment: Since `midvalues(j)`  depends indirectly from `ODE(j)` (through `k1(j)`) you're kinda asking for a call to `ODE` with itself as an argument. You can't do that directly in C++. I think either you should do some math first to transform the equations, either you should implement a convergence algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**variant on C++:**

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    double voltage(double v) {
        return v;
    }
    double hdot(double h) {
        return h * 2;
    }
    double ndot(double n) {
        return n * 3;
    }

    typedef double(*eqpointer)(double);

int main() {
    eqpointer ODE[] = { voltage, hdot, ndot };
    int eq_num = sizeof(ODE) / sizeof(*ODE); // quantity elements in ODE[]
    double *midvalues = new double[eq_num]; //change to variant (ty M_M)

    for (int j = 0; j < eq_num; j++) {
        midvalues[j] = (*ODE[j])((j + 1) * 10) / 2;  // Value For Example
        printf("midvalues[%d]: %f\n", j, midvalues[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

stdout

```
*** midvalues[0]: 5.000000<br>
*** midvalues[1]: 20.000000<br>
*** midvalues[2]: 45.000000<br>
```

[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/HgjpQ9)

variant with std::vector (ty to @M.M)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
    using namespace std;

    double voltage(double v) {
        return v;
    }
    double hdot(double h) {
        return h * 2;
    }
    double ndot(double n) {
        return n * 3;
    }

    typedef double(*eqpointer)(double);

int main() {
    vector<eqpointer> ODE = { voltage, hdot, ndot };
    int eq_num = ODE.size(); // quantity elements in ODE[]
    vector<double> midvalues(eq_num);
    for (int j = 0; j < eq_num; j++) {
        midvalues[j] = (*ODE[j])((j + 1) * 10) / 2;  // Value For Example
        printf("midvalues[%d]: %f\n", j, midvalues[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/qD2sCL)

**variant on C:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

double voltage(double v) {
    return v;
}
double hdot(double h) {
    return h * 2;
}
double ndot(double n) {
    return n * 3;
}

typedef double(*eqpointer)(double);

int main() {
    eqpointer ODE[] = { voltage, hdot, ndot };
    int eq_num = sizeof(ODE)/sizeof(*ODE);

    // declared only for this examle
    double result;
    double k1 [eq_num], oneloop[eq_num], midvalues[eq_num];
    // or best malloc(eq_num * sizeof(double)); from stdlib

    for (int j = 0; j < eq_num; j++) {

        k1[j] = (*ODE[j])((j + 1) * 10);    // random arguments ODE for example only
        oneloop[j] =20 * (*ODE[j])(j + 1);
        midvalues[j] = (k1[j] + oneloop[j]) / 2;  
        result = (*ODE[j])(midvalues[j]);

        printf("*** %d) k1[]: %f, oneloop[]: %f, midvalues[]: %f result: %f\n",
            j, k1[j], oneloop[j], midvalues[j], result);
    }
    return 0;
}

#stdout 
*** 0) k1[]: 10.000000, oneloop[]: 20.000000, midvalues[]: 15.000000 result: 15.000000
*** 1) k1[]: 40.000000, oneloop[]: 80.000000, midvalues[]: 60.000000 result: 120.000000
*** 2) k1[]: 90.000000, oneloop[]: 180.000000, midvalues[]: 135.000000 result: 405.000000
```

[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/ZjIZUc)

Comment: use `vector` instead of `new double`

Comment: thank you!(but this varables declaration  only for this example) and question to author @Erez Sabran : yours project is C++ or C? both tag in question

Comment: OP uses code that is not valid in C so I would assume it is a C++